# SQL Group By with multiple counts

Tags: sql, group-by, count, pivot

I'm trying to group a list of services together along with the number of applicants in each service, but I also need a count on the status each applicant is in.

**Applicants** table

```
serviceID  clientID    applicantID   status  
----------------------------------------------------
   1          41           1           1 (Processing)
   1          41           16          1 (Processing)
   1          41           15          2 (Ready)
   2          41           12          1 (Processing)
   2          41           18          3 (Complete)
```

**Service** table:

```
 serviceID   serviceName     
--------------------------
   1         Full Service     
   2         Part Service
```

Results need to look like:

```
serviceName    totalApplicants  processingCount  readyCount  completeCount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Full Service        3                 2              1            0 
Part Service        2                 1              0            1
```

I've got the following, but it's returning the same count in each of the columns:-

```
SELECT
    Services.serviceName,
    (COUNT(Applicants.applicantID)) AS totalApplicants, 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Applicants.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS processingCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Applicants.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS readyCount, 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Applicants.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS completeCount
FROM
    Applicants
LEFT JOIN 
    Services ON Applicants.serviceID = Services.serviceID   
WHERE 
    Applicants.clientID = @CompanyID
GROUP BY
    Services.serviceName
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: @Sherry8212 . . . Your query looks ok, in the sense that tit should not be returning the same values in the columns.

Comment: Just tested you data with Gordon query, it works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/73251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    s.serviceName,
    count(s.serviceID) totalApplicants,
    sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) processingCount,
    sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) readyCount,
    sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) completeCount
from service s
left join applicants a on a.serviceID = s.serviceID AND a.clientID = @CompanyID
group by s.serviceID, s.serviceName
```

The conditional expression use standard `case` expression; depending on the database that you are actually using, neater alternatives may exists.

Comment: This got it for me

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be fine, but it can be simplified to:

```
SELECT s.serviceName,
       COUNT(a.AppicantId) AS totalApplicants, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS processingCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS readyCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completeCount
FROM Services s LEFT JOIN
     Applicants a
     ON a.serviceID = s.serviceID AND
        a.clientID = @CompanyID
GROUP BY s.serviceName ;
```

Notes:

- It looks like you want a row for every service, so that should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.
- Hence the filtering on the company goes into the `ON` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- No `ISNULL()` is needed (and I prefer `COALESCE()` over `ISNULL()`).